# Managing groups of users

Tags: users

Please help find the modules that allows me to create the following scenario

1. Admin can create a User-A
   a. User-A will receive an activation email
2. After activation User-A will be able to:
   a. create User-B with another permissions, which will also recieve an activation email
   b. create groups of Users-B
   c. assign Users-B to the selected group
   d. managing and see only Users-B which he created
   e. assign content to the selected group
3. After activation User-B will have access to the content of the group to which he is assigned.

I will be grateful for an any help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [Organic Groups](https://drupal.org/project/og), and if needed, [Role Delegation](https://drupal.org/project/role_delegation). I think you can get by with just Organic Groups maybe ... Drupal core can send out notifications of new accounts by itself upon account creation.

Orangic Groups is a contrib module:

> Enable users to create and manage their own 'groups'. Each group can
>   have subscribers, and maintains a group home page where subscribers
>   communicate amongst themselves.
>
> They do so by posting the usual node types: blog, story, page, etc. A
>   block is shown on the group home page which facilitates these posts.
>   The block also provides summary information about the group.
>
> Groups may be selective or not. Selective groups require approval in
>   order to become a member, or even invitation -only groups. There are
>   lots of preferences to configure groups as you need.

A synopsis from Role Delegation project page is:

> This module allows site administrators to grant some roles the
>   authority to assign selected roles to users, without them needing the
>   administer permissions permission.
>
> For each role, Role Delegation provides a new assign ROLE role
>   permission to allow the assignment of that role.

Fully understanding and leveraging these modules to fit your workflow, business logic, etc is a task I leave up to you. Your question is far from simple.